# Vue JS, make multiple arrays from one array of JSON, based on a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuejs2

I'm newer to Vue JS and am trying to use what they offer to go through a JSON array to make multiple arrays based on a shared object prop value.  Based on this JSON:

```
    {
    fields: [
        {
            "group": "group1",
            "label": "label1",
            "value": "value1",
        },
        {
            "group": "group1",
            "label": "label2",
            "value": "value2",
        },
        {
            "group": "group2",
            "label": "label3",
            "value": "value3",
        },
        {
            "group": "group2",
            "label": "label4",
            "value": "value4",
        },
    ],
}
```

I need to make different arrays per "group", so I need to make a different array for "group1" values, then as the loop gets to "group2" values stop and make a new array of all the group 2 objects. The "group" values could be anything, I will not know them ahead of time.

I need to end up with this:

```
group1Fields: [
    {
        "group": "group1",
        "label": "label1",
        "value": "value1",
    },
    {
        "group": "group1",
        "label": "label2",
        "value": "value2",
    }
],
group2Fields: [
    {
        "group": "group2",
        "label": "label3",
        "value": "value3",
    },
    {
        "group": "group2",
        "label": "label4",
        "value": "value4",
    }
]
```

I'm currently investigating array mapping and even using a computed property or method, would appreciate any advice.

Currently studying the YouTube channel "LearnVue" on loops in Vue.  https://www.youtube.com/c/LearnVue

Comment: If the `group` values could be anything, do you intend to store them in an object with the key being the group name? This has nothing to do with VueJS and is purely a JS operation.

Comment: most likely yes, I have just begun but that makes sense to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [
          {"group": "group1", "label": "label1", "value": "value1",},
          {"group": "group1", "label": "label2", "value": "value2",},
          {"group": "group2", "label": "label3", "value": "value3",},
          {"group": "group2", "label": "label4", "value": "value4",},
      ],
      grp: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    groups() {
      return [...new Set(this.fields.map(f => f.group))]
    },
    filteredGroups() {
      return this.grp ? this.fields.filter(g => g.group === this.grp) : this.fields
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="(item, i) in groups" :key="i">
    <button @click="grp = item">{{ item }}</button>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(group, i) in filteredGroups" :key="i">
      {{ group }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nikola, this is the type of thing I was looking for, I thought I might need a computed prop